# What is the most efficient way to search text on a big table?

Tags: c#, sql-server, wcf, optimization

I need to search a text field (varchar 500) on a table with about 150,000 rows.

The first option I tried was executing a stored procedure directly on the db server which looks something like:

```
Select p.ProductID, 
    p.ProductDescription, 
    p.SalesPrice 
From Products p 
Where p.ProductDescription Like '%' + @PartialDescription + '%'
```

The result was pretty slow. Even with index on ProductDescription, performance was not fast enough.

The next solution I came up with works in following steps:

1. Read the whole Products table into List of Type Product and cache it.
2. Everytime I need to make a search, I go through the collection and do the string comparision as below

   ```
   List<Product> searchResultItems = new List<Product>();
   for (int i = 0; i < cachedProducts.Count; i++)
   {
       Product p = cachedProducts[i];

       if (p.Description.IndexOf(partialDescription, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)>=0)
       {
           searchResultItems.Add(p);
       }
   }
   return searchResultItems;
   ```

This solution is little faster than searching it directly into the database. 
By caching the table in memory, it avoids database calls to a large extent. 
However, its still slow in comparision to the legacy system (built more than 10 years ago on FileMaker).
I do not have access to the source code of legacy system and do not know much about it.

With MS SQL Server 2008 database, code written on C# and cache utilizing ObjectCache on System.Runtime.Caching, I was expecting my solution to easily outperform the legacy system. Embarrassingly, its not the case. 
How can I optimize my search method? What am I doing wrong? Above function resides in a WCF Service and is consumed (basicHttpBinding) by a web application without any fancy controls. What can I do to make it faster?

Searching directly into the database, can it be a better solution with any kind of optimizations? How can I optimize it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are searching on a value with a wildcard prefix, an index will not be able to be used hence it will always be doing a table scan.

You could look into [Full Text Search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

Comment: So searching at db level (with FTS) is the best? No point at all doing it in application layer? (same question for @Alok as well) Any insights?

Comment: IMHO, unless you are dealing with a small number of rows, then I'd do it at the db level. Bringing back all rows and doing it in the application layer wouldn't be great for larger quantities of data.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using MS SQL 2008, I would suggest use Full Text Search. Enable FT Index on your table, and then follow the FTS hints to search the text.

Answer (score 1):

> Even with index on ProductDescription, performance was not fast enough.

SQL for beginners:

> '%' + @PartialDescription + '%'

Triggersa  full table scan, an index CAN NOT BE USED because of the beginnnign "%". Standard indices are useles to search for individual words.

If you can deal with removing that - then basically you get index use and should get immediate returns

> on a table with about 150,000 rows

Toy size. Unlesss you run on a 2gb vps.

I would eliminate the % or go to a full text index.

Comment: A table with 150,000 rows is a "Toy" for you aye? You sir, are a very wise person.
+1 for your very encouraging comment. I'll now go back to my desk and play with the toy.
Thank you.

Comment: it is. I live in a world where you load 40 million rows per day into tables. We process 450.000 business objects in 7 minutes - some of them having close 20 a quarter million detail rows. 150.000 was small 10 years ago. 20 years ago foxpro had no problem handling rows with 1 million entries. Get real - today you have workstations with 16gb memory on the smaller end, database servers with 250gb memory.